# Keeping maximum and minimum values in a logical sequence

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

Consider this data:

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(2922, 4018, 5113, 7305, 8035, 
12053, 14975, 16436, 17532, 17897), class = "Date"), HAM = c(1016.89391375364, 
-1269.0910012255, -1097.9927692669, -5069.52785909119, 3168.39687262048, 
-1265.24208195278, -1218.5560466457, 1463.67252927616, 1259.20509267793, 
1267.89637533522), State = c("Expansion", "Contraction", "Contraction", 
"Contraction", "Expansion", "Contraction", "Contraction", "Expansion", 
"Contraction", "Expansion"), sd = c("larger", "smaller", "smaller", 
"smaller", "larger", "smaller", "smaller", "larger", "larger", 
"larger")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to keep a logical sequence of "Expansion" followed by "Contraction", taking into consideration the maximum value (for Expansion) and minimum value (for "Contraction"). Expected result is this data frame:

```
ndf <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(2922, 7305, 8035, 12053, 16436
), class = "Date"), HAM = c(1016.89391375364, -5069.52785909119, 
3168.39687262048, -1265.24208195278, 1463.67252927616), State = c("Expansion", 
"Contraction", "Expansion", "Contraction", "Expansion"), sd = c("larger", 
"smaller", "larger", "smaller", "larger")), row.names = c(1L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: the 9th row in df has State=='contraction' with sd=='larger' and a positive value for HAM. is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: why are rows 9 and 10 of `df` not included in `ndf`? They seem to meet your criteria.

Comment: You should post your attempts to solve this problem.

Comment: It's related to the repetition of "sd". I commented on your answer. Sorry for not mentioning it. Thanks for your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is encoding the sequential expansion/contractions as groups. My goto for this is `rle` run length encoding. Based on your criteria it seems that rows 9 and 10 of `df` should be included in the final result.

```
ndf_seq <- rle(df$State)
ndf2 <- split(df, rep(seq_len(length(ndf_seq$lengths)), 
                      ndf_seq$lengths))
ndf2 <- lapply(ndf2, function(x) x[which.max(abs(x$HAM)), ])
ndf2 <- do.call(rbind, ndf2)

ndf2
         Date       HAM       State      sd
#1 1978-01-01  1016.894   Expansion  larger
#2 1990-01-01 -5069.528 Contraction smaller
#3 1992-01-01  3168.397   Expansion  larger
#4 2003-01-01 -1265.242 Contraction smaller
#5 2015-01-01  1463.673   Expansion  larger
#6 2018-01-01  1259.205 Contraction  larger
#7 2019-01-01  1267.896   Expansion  larger
```

Here is a tidyverse solution too:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(data.table::rleid(State)) %>% 
  filter(abs(HAM)==max(abs(HAM)))
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks a lot! I forgot to mention that I did not want "sd" to repeat. I just added one line to your code: ```filter(!duplicated(rleid(sd)))```